# Building a pyramidal horn antenna radio telescope - need advice

Tags: rf, antenna

I am currently trying to build a pyramidal horn antenna. The horn antenna is designed for the hydrogen line at 1420 MHz. The copper probe at the end of the waveguide is soldered onto a 4-hole SMA panel mount.

I'm using this [LNA](https://www.nooelec.com/store/sawbird-h1.html) and this [SDR](https://www.nooelec.com/store/checkout/cart/) and this [SMA Connector Kit](https://www.nooelec.com/store/sma-adapter-connectivity-kit.html). I am struggling to find a 4-hole SMA male panel mount which I can use to solder the copper wire on to. Are there any alternatives which I can use to fix this issue?

Here is a link to the documentation I am following: https://physicsopenlab.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Hydrogen-Line-Project-Documentation.pdf

Comment: up to which frequency does this need to work well? What's the size of your horn antenna? What does a panel mount SMA connector have to do with all this?

Comment: *Are there any alternatives* <-- Alternatives to which part?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've made an edit which should make what I'm asking a bit more clear

Comment: @Andyaka Alternatives to using a panel mount as I am unable to find one

Comment: sorry, that helped very little: "soldered to the end" of what? I can guess you mean a feed? But what kind of feed? We can't read the construction plans in your head, sadly ;)

Comment: @Skantzy what specific part are you looking for that requires an alternative? Be also aware that questions seeking recommendations for products (and alternatives) are usually closed.

Comment: Have you (OP) determined the placement, length, and orientation of the "probe" in the end of the horn?  This seems to be a bigger problem than the type of coax connector that is used.  A sketch would help us understand the problem better.

Comment: If you're following an online guide to building your antenna it would help if you add a link to it in your question. That would save us from guessing what you are doing.

Comment: @GrahamNye I've added a link to the documentation I am following, hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

A Google search for "panel mount sma" shows a selection of devices from major electronics distributors. (Here in the UK Mouser, Digikey, RS, Farnell. Elsewhere you may have a different selection.)

> this SMA Connector Kit.

Try to minimise the number of adapters you string together especially for the weak signal connection between the horn and the LNA. If the horn is rigid enough you could use a four hole male plug on the waveguide section and attach the LNA directly to the horn.

If the horn is less rigid so that the weight of the LNA would make the waveguide to co-ax SMA probe flex you could use a four hole female jack on the horn and buy a pre-made short male-male SMA lead to connect it to the LNA.

After the LNA it's less critical to avoid adapter losses but the fewer adapters you use the more reliable your connections will be. Try to plan your cables to use the correct connectors without adapters where possible.

For readers mystified by what OP is trying to do I assume they are trying to build their own [waveguide to coax transition](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/waveguide-to-coax-transitions) (because commercial ones are really expensive).

Comment: Determining the placement, length, and orientation of the "probe" seems to be a bigger problem than the type of coax connector that is used.

Comment: @SteveSh Probably so but OP isn't asking about that. So either OP has adequate build instructions for the probe or they'll be back with a second question. I'd find it harder to answer that one, beyond "look at Google".